# Beautiful Soup script not delivering desired CSV output

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping/BS4 and am having a problem getting this csv file to list all of the members. My problem is the CSV is listing one member's information in repeat over multiple lines. If anyone has any ideas to fix this, would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import requests
    import csv
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    r = requests.get('https://vermontmaple.org/basic-member-list')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

    with open('list.csv', 'w') as f:

        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow(['name', 'address', 'phone'])

        for company in soup.findAll('div', class_='directory_item selected'):
            maple_name = soup.find('div', class_='name').get_text(strip=True)
            maple_address = soup.find('div', class_='address').get_text(strip=True)
            maple_phone = soup.find('div', class_='phone').get_text(strip=True)

            writer.writerow([maple_name, maple_address, maple_phone])

        f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `soup.find` to  `company.find` inside the forloop

```
for company in soup.findAll('div', class_='directory_item selected'):
        maple_name = company.find('div', class_='name').get_text(strip=True)
        maple_address = company.find('div', class_='address').get_text(strip=True)
        maple_phone = company.find('div', class_='phone').get_text(strip=True)
```

there is no need for a `f.close()`